# redirecting find standard output as an argument to tar command

Tags: linux

```
$ find playground -name "file_a"  | tar cf - --files-from=- | gzip > playground.tgz
```

can't understand why we used both `-` in `cf -` alongside with `--files-from=-`

isn't `-` rediredting all the standard output to `tar cf` already ?

Answer (score 0):

The use of the same `-` symbol could be confusing, but it has a different meaning in each case.

When used with `cf -`, it means that instead of naming a file to write to, [tar should write the archive to standard output](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/file.html#file):

> If you use ‘-’ as an archive-name, tar reads the archive from standard input (when listing or extracting files), or writes it to **standard output** (when creating an archive).

When used with `--files-from=-` it means to [get names to extract or create from the given filename](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/files.html), and:

> If you give a single dash as a file name for ‘--files-from’, (i.e., you specify either --files-from=- or -T -), then the file names are read from **standard input**.

(my emphasis on reading standard input).